# How can we use existing selenium scripts (java) to get some end to end performance metrics (low load)

Tags: performance, selenium, testing, client, client-side

I am trying to leverage existing selenium automation scripts in java developed by Automation team to get some end to end performance metrics (total page load time etc) - very minimal load, in parallel to api load testing.

Please let me know what will be the most efficient way to do that. Also i am looking for making minimum changes to the selenium scripts because this will be an ongoing activity with each release and i am looking for to use functional scripts as it is with performance wrapper around it.

Your suggestions will be appreciated.

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using Selenium for load testing. If setting up dedicated perf tests is not an option, you could at least do this:

```
//Put this into the loaded scripts of your page under test. Make sure loadTimeMs is a global variable or saved to a hidden control.
var loadTimeMs = 0;
var pageContentRecieved = (new Date()).getTime();
$(window).load(function () {
    var pageLoaded = (new Date()).getTime();
    loadTimeMs = pageLoaded - pageContentRecieved;
});
```

That will give you an approximate time to load the sync parts of a page. More importantly is the time for the web server to provide you the content. I recommend doing that in a controlled way by calling the page back as an API in the javascript.

```
//Return previous value for page load time.
JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
int pageLoad = je.executeAsyncScript("return loadTimeMs;");

//Goes into Java code.
je = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
int apiResponseTime = je.executeAsyncScript(
    "var loadTimeMs = 0;" +
    "var pageContentRecieved = (new Date()).getTime();" +
    "$.ajax({url: "demo_test.txt", success: function(result){" +
        "var pageLoaded = (new Date()).getTime();" +
        "return pageLoaded - pageContentRecieved;" +
    "}});" +
);
int fullLoadTime = pageLoad + apiResponseTime;
```

Finally, add the two values together for a rough/approximate performance check in the middle of your existing selenium tests.

Comment: thanks @Asyranok for your suggestion, as i mentioned earlier the purpose of this test is not load but to measure page load time with 1 or 2 concurrent users. We are planning to execute this test in parallel with Backend apis load test. Now coming back to your suggestion can this code be rewritten in java as our selenium scripts are written in that language.

Comment: Right, my test is NOT testing "load". It is testing page load time. 

My example above is for your Java. I copied it from my Java Selenium framework. So the first code block is javascript. If you are testing a webpage, then it can read Javascript as that is the global language of the internet as far as scripting. And I am suggesting that the first block of code go onto your page being tested.

The second block of code is Java, and is executing Javascript on the page under test.